# What CSS styling to give more spaces between hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

I have an ASP.NET application with contains a list of hyperlinks.  After each hyperlink, there is a br tag that puts each hyperlink on their own line.  I want to increase the spacing between each line.  I don't want to add another br trag since that does not provide the control I am looking for.  I have tried different CSS styling without any change.  What CSS styling do I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add margin or padding to top of your BR tags eg.

```
br { margin:10px 0; }
```

If that isn't feasible, then make your hyperlinks block level and add margin or padding to top of them eg.

```
a { display:block; margin:10px 0; }
```

Using the latter method you don't require the BR tags anymore.

Answer (score 7):

For the hyperlinks you could use `display:block;` and `margin-bottom:[some value]` style/CSS properties, you wouldn't need to have your BR elements, and you would gain much more control.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are looking for is `line-height`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html

even though this might be the better/'nicer' solution:

```
<ul id="mylinklist">
    <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this style:

```
ul#mylinklist{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#mylinklist li{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<br />` elements and instead give those anchor elements a [`display:block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) property.

Then use `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` or `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` to increase the space between.

Answer (score 0):

use `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`

```
a{
margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```